# .NET 4.5 API with Identity.Core v2 - User.Identity.Name is always null

Tags: .net, asp.net-identity

I am trying to access the user's name that submitted a request to an ApiController.

```
string uname = User.Identity.Name;
```

User.Identity contains:

```
{System.Security.Claims.ClaimsIdentity}
    [System.Security.Claims.ClaimsIdentity]: {System.Security.Claims.ClaimsIdentity}
    AuthenticationType: "Bearer"
    IsAuthenticated: true
    Name: null
```

The Name property is always null.

I've also tried using

```
string uname = HttpContext.Current.Request.LogonUserIdentity.Name
```

HttpContext.Current.Request.LogonUserIdentity contains:

```
{System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity}
    base: {System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity}
    AccessToken: {Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeAccessTokenHandle}
    AuthenticationType: "Bearer"
    Claims: {System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.get_Claims}
    DeviceClaims: Count = 0
    Groups: {System.Security.Principal.IdentityReferenceCollection}
    ImpersonationLevel: Impersonation
    IsAnonymous: false
    IsAuthenticated: true
    IsGuest: false
    IsSystem: false
    Name: "IIS APPPOOL\\DefaultAppPool"
    Owner: {S-1-5-82-3006700770-424185619-1745488364-794895919-4004696415}
    Token: 2436
    User: {S-1-5-82-3006700770-424185619-1745488364-794895919-4004696415}
    UserClaims: Count = 11
```

You'll notice the Name is the Application Pool's name.

This is what the Startup.CS looks like:

```
public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            ConfigureOAuth(app);
            HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();
            WebApiConfig.Register(config);
            app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);
            app.UseWebApi(config);
        }

        public void ConfigureOAuth(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions OAuthServerOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions()
            {
                AllowInsecureHttp = true,
                TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/token"),
                AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromHours(1),
                Provider = new SimpleAuthorizationServerProvider(), 
                
            };
            
            
            // Token Generation
            app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(OAuthServerOptions);
            app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions());
        }
    }
```

This is the SimpleAuthorizationServerProvider class:

```
public class SimpleAuthorizationServerProvider : OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider
    {
        public override async Task ValidateClientAuthentication(OAuthValidateClientAuthenticationContext context)
        {
            context.Validated();
        }

        public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
        {

            context.OwinContext.Response.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", new[] { "*" });

            using (AuthRepository _repo = new AuthRepository())
            {
                IdentityUser user = await _repo.FindUser(context.UserName, context.Password);

                if (user == null)
                {
                    context.SetError("invalid_grant", "The user name or password is incorrect.");
                    return;
                }
            }

            var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(context.Options.AuthenticationType);
            identity.AddClaim(new Claim("sub", context.UserName));
            identity.AddClaim(new Claim("role", "user"));

            context.Validated(identity);

        }
    }
```

How am i able to get the name of the authenticated API user that is making the Request?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do this by updating the SimpleAuthorizationServerProvider class:
changed:

```
identity.AddClaim(new Claim("sub", context.UserName));
```

to

```
identity.AddClaim(new Claim("userName", context.UserName));
```

Then used claims to retrieve the userName property:

```
var identity = (ClaimsIdentity)User.Identity;
string userName = (from c in identity.Claims
                   where c.Type == "userName"
                   select c.Value).FirstOrDefault();
```

I am not sure if this is the only way to do this or the most efficient but it's working